# Storing Multiple Matrices in a Cell array (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am currently attempting to generate 30 different matrices and store them in a cell array, but when I run the program I just have a cell array with 30 copies of the same matrix. What am I doing wrong?

```
m_A = 20;
ID = 3754;
m_B = .002*ID + 3.1;
J_A = 0.0013*ID + 0.188;
g = -9.81;
i = 1;
n = 30/i;
%stores matrices in a cell array
matrixresults = cell(1, n);
for k = 1:n
%generates A matrices
    for M = 0:i:30
        J_C = .5*M*((.1)^2); 
        matrixresults{k} = [(m_A), 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0; 
                      (5*J_A), 0, -0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
                      (10*J_C), 0, 0, -0.1, 0, .1, 0;
                      0, M, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1;
                      0, (10*J_C), 0, 0, 0, -0.1, 0.1;
                      0, m_B, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0;
                      0.5, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];    
    end 
 end
```

Comment: There are two loops in your code, which visit 30(k) cells 30(M) times, so only the last time ( when `M=30`) are saved.

Comment: How can I fix the code so that all of them are saved?

Comment: Save them all are quite useless because your code generates the same item 30 times. See my answer, I hope it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clc; clear;
m_A = 20;
ID = 3754;
m_B = .002*ID + 3.1;
J_A = 0.0013*ID + 0.188;
g = -9.81;
i = 1;
n = 30/i;
%stores matrices in a cell array
A = cell(1, n);
for k = 1:i:30
        J_C = .5*k*((.1)^2); 
        A{k} = [(m_A), 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0; 
                      (5*J_A), 0, -0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
                      (10*J_C), 0, 0, -0.1, 0, .1, 0;
                      0, k, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1;
                      0, (10*J_C), 0, 0, 0, -0.1, 0.1;
                      0, m_B, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0;
                      0.5, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
end
```

Comment: Emm, I changed your `matrixresults` to `A` since it is too long for me. Besides, in your inner loop there will be 31 different item, you have to check about it.

Comment: That's alright. welcome to StackOverflow! @user9348207